# CRA - window object is undefined - jest/react

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I have an issue in my tests that flag up a window variable as undefined. But I don't know where in the setupTests.tsx, I would need to define it. So far the variable is used as so:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/config.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**config.js**

```
window._env_ = {
  REACT_APP_URL: "https://apiurl.com"
}
```

how it is used in the app:

```
declare const window: Window &
    typeof globalThis & {
        _env_: any
    }

const url = window._env_.REACT_APP_URL;
export const apiUrl = url;
```

**setupTests.tsx** I did try adding it here but it's still not working

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { setLogger } from 'react-query'
import { server } from './mocks/server'
declare const window: Window &

typeof globalThis & {
    _env_: any
}

window._env_.REACT_APP_URL = "https://wwww.xxxxx.com"

beforeAll(() => server.listen())
// Reset any request handlers that we may add during the tests,
// so they don't affect other tests.


afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers())

// Clean up after the tests are finished.
afterAll(() => server.close())
```

The error that stops the tests:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'REACT_APP_URL')

      4 |     }
      5 |
    > 6 | const url = window._env_.REACT_APP_URL;
        |                          ^
      7 | export const apiUrl = url;
      8 |
      9 |
```

Any idea's for use with Create React App setup?

Comment: Any reasons for *not* using a `.env` file and putting the environment variable there? [Docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables)

Comment: To be honest, it's just because of how deployment is done, ideally the `.env` is the way to go

Comment: Okay, and what is the `config.js` file for, what is it configuring?

Comment: So, this uses docker container and the config.js has a windows variable in it that when it deploys to different environments the windows object variables get picked up

Comment: Okay, so means you have this env variable defined only in prod and not in dev. So, you can simply fallback to a hardcoded value in `dev`, `const url = window._env_.REACT_APP_URL || "https://wwww.xxxxx.com";`

Comment: but which value would it take first? If the windows variable is undefined it would fallback to the url ?

Comment: Yes, correct! I've added an answer please check, hope it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have the environment variable defined in test environment, you can simply fallback to a hardcoded `url`, as shown below.

```
declare const window: Window &
  typeof globalThis & {
    _env_: any
  }

const url = window._env_.REACT_APP_URL || "https://wwww.xxxxx.com";
export const apiUrl = url;
```

So, in environments where the `REACT_APP_URL` environment variable is defined it will use that and if it's *not* defined it will pick up the hardcoded value.

And, now you can remove all the additional code from `setupTests.tsx`.